# Rough regex for multiline text with optional group and named captures at the end of each match

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I want to capture some ifconfig output (example below) and from that, I want to have interface names, flags, IP address and netmask (if they exist), status (which also may not exist in loopback devices)

```
re0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=8209b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,WOL_MAGIC,LINKSTATE>
    ether 00:30:18:c6:03:f0
    inet 192.168.16.67 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.16.255 
    inet6 fe80::230:18ff:fec6:3f0%re0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
re1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=8209b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,WOL_MAGIC,LINKSTATE>
    ether 00:30:18:c6:03:f1
    inet6 fe80::230:18ff:fec6:3f1%re1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2 
    nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect (none)
    status: no carrier
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

and I have managed take it up to this point;

```
^(?<interface>(?:[^\s:]+))(?=: flags):\s(?:flags=\d+<(?<flags>(?:[\w,]+))>).*?(?:(?:inet (?<ip_address>(?:\d+\.?){4})|$)? (?:netmask 0x(?<netmask>(?:\w++\.?))|$)).*?(?:status: (?<status>(?:[\w ]++)))
```

but this only captures normal interfaces not loopback device because of status line. And if you make the status line optional by putting a question mark at end of status line match group, it does not match even if status line exist for some reasons that I can not manage to understand.

A problem waiting for geniuses all over the world to solve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this fix:

```
^(?<interface>(?:[^\s:]+)):\s+(?:flags=\d+<(?<flags>(?:[\w,]+))>)(?:(?!\b(?:flags=|inet\b|status:)).)*(?:(?:inet\s+(?<ip_address>(?:\d+\.?){4})|$)?\s+(?:netmask\s+0x(?<netmask>(?:\w++\.?))|$))(?:(?!status:|\binet\b|^[^\s:]+:\s+flags=\d+).)*(?:status:\s+(?<status>(?:[\w ]+)))?
```

Main points of what I changed:

1. Removed unnecessary look-ahead `(?=: flags)`
2. Added `(?:(?!status:|^[^\s:]+:\s+flags=\d+).)*` instead of last `.*?` (featuring [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) that allows us to match only up to what we need)
3. Added the `?` quantifier for the last `status` capture group.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM2oG7/4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is a lot closer then mine but if you add any more interface with existing inet field it doesn't see those IP addresses after an entry without inet filed such as re1 :( see: [link](https://regex101.com/r/aM2oG7/2)

Comment: I updated the answer. Please [check updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM2oG7/4).